# How to Copy and sync cells from multiple sheets to one sheet, based on the Background Color of the Cell

Tags: google-sheets

``I am new in apps script google sheet and i try to create a function, that i can sync from multiple sheets in one sheets on same spreadsheet base color.I have no idea how to select the entire row or if the condition I'm using to get the Background color is right.I was trying to do it. Can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

```
    function copycellsBasedColor() {
 var sourcesheetNames = \["sheet1","sheet2", "sheet3"\]
 var targetsheetName = "Sheet5";
 var sheet5= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet5");
   for (var i=0; i \< sourcesheetNames.length; i++){
   var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sourcesheetNames\[i\]);

 var sourcheRange = sourcesheet.getDataRange();
 var sourchevalues = sourchsheet.getSheetValues;
 var sourceBackgrounds = sourcheRange.getBackgrounds();

 for (var row = 0; row \< sourceValues.length; row++) {
 for (var col = 0; col \< sourceValues\[0\].length; col++) {
   var cellValue = sourceValues\[row\]\[col\];
  var cellBackground = sourceBackgrounds\[row\]\[col\];  if (cellBackground === "#00ff00")
      targetSheet.getRange(row + 1, col + 1).setValue(cellValue);}}}
```